# ver tabla con las creaciones del usuario logueado

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esta tabla de productos y quiero que se muestre los valores de solo ese por el usuario que esta logueado.

mi controlador

```
public function mostrarTablausu()
    {          

        $productos = productos::with('usuario','categoria','estado','mensajeson')->select('productos.*');


        return  Datatables::of($productos)->addColumn('action', function($productos)
        {
            return 
            '<a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="">Aprovar</a>'.
            '<a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="">Rechazar</a>'.
            '<a onclick=""  class="btn btn-warning" >Verificar</a>';

        })->make(true);
    }
```

no se como me muestre solo los productos que creo solo el usuario logeado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usas el facade Auth para sacar el id del usuario logueado y en el where lo relacionas con el primary key de tu tabla usuario.

```
public function mostrarTablausu()
{          

    $productos = productos::with('usuario','categoria','estado','mensajeson')->select('productos.*')->where('usuario.id','=',Auth::user()->id);


    return  Datatables::of($productos)->addColumn('action', function($productos)
    {
        return 
        '<a type="button" class="btn btn-info" href="">Aprovar</a>'.
        '<a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="">Rechazar</a>'.
        '<a onclick=""  class="btn btn-warning" >Verificar</a>';

    })->make(true);
}
```

Comment: super me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

El helper `auth` (o el [facade Auth](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)) te ayuda a traer la información del usuario logueado:

```
// para obtener al usuario:
$usuario = auth()->user();

// o solo para traer el id del usuario:
$id_usuario = auth()->id();
```

Entonces, lo pendiente que te queda por hacer es ajustar tu *query* para que traiga los elementos que estén relacionados únicamente con ese usuario. Un ejemplo simple:

```
// obtenemos los productos vinculados con el usuario logueado
// pd: aquí asumo que existe la relación "productos" en el modelo Usuario
$productos = App\Usuario::find(auth()->id())->productos;
// con lo siguiente vamos a cargar el resto de relaciones:
$productos->load('usuario','categoria','estado','mensajeson');
```

Documentación:

- [Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)
- [Lazy Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)